# Formula to filter table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there a formula on excel that would allow one to filter a table set like the example below?

The formula need to be an OR function, so when I look at a participant who plays Basketball it does not delete other participants that play other sports not including Basketball like Daniel Ollo.

```
1 = Participant Plays Sport; 0 = Participant Does Not Play Sport

        Basketball  Soccer  Tennis  Baseball    Hockey  Running
John Doe    1          0       1       1          0       0
Kelly Anne  1          0       0       0          1       1
Daniel Ollo 0          0       0       0          0       1
Luis Packer 1          0       0       1          1       0
```

When searching for a specific sport i.e. Basketball, Hockey & Running the excel sheet would appear like this:

```
Basketball
John Doe
Kelly Anne
Luis Packer

Hockey
Kelly Anne
Luis Packer

Running
Daniel Ollo
Kelly Anne
```

Comment: Is a filter on the table an option? Or do you need these results printed elsewhere in the workbook?

Comment: You'd rather use a formula, over a filter? Is that correct? And have you tried to use MS Access? It's really the way to go, because essentially you want to QUERY a DATABASE.

Answer (score 2):

Or function is not enough to find the names this is another method to do it:
Start by Define Name for each sport:
Select all numbers under the column of Basketball (without the Header) and click in the up left of the formula Bar(where the reference is) and write Basketball the same as the Header
Repeat the same for each column
Define Name for all: Soccer, Tennis, Baseball... Name for the column of names

In A8 write the sport you are searching for example Basketball
In A9 write the following array formula and drag it down to cover the same number of rows as your initial Data

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Name,SMALL(IF(INDIRECT($A$8)=1,ROW(INDIRECT($A$8))-1,""),ROW()-8)),"")`     Press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

*Name* is a define name for all the column of names starting by the first name and till the last
Indirect($A$8) is the array of numbers for the corresponding numbers

8 is the row number where you wrote the sport example Basketball
Whenever you change the name of the sport the name of participants will change eventually

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good template for you to use to get you going. Using the MATCH and OFFSET functions work well for your situation.

The MATCH function returns the first occurrence of a condition and returns the row number. =MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])

The OFFSET function allows you to have a selected array and then move from it with formulas.

I set up an example similar to yours:
[image]

Instead of returning the names of the people I returned the row that their name is at. I feel this will help show you how to do it better. Of course you can include another match to obtain the names once you have the row number.

Notice the second group where it lists the sports with the numbers.
[image]

The first formula looks like above using the MATCH function only. Pretty straightforward here for how it finds the first occurrence.

[image]

The cells below the first one should look like above. This looks up like the first cell does with the MATCH function but offsets it based on the row the previous search found. The IFERROR is simply there to display a blank if nothing is found. I put the dollar sign on the rows as you don't want those adjusting at all. The column can though so you can just drag the formula to the right and everything will work.

Hope this helps you learn how to use MATCH and OFFSET.